# Typescript derived class as callback signature

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm trying to make a base class that issues a method for throtteling highly frequented event calls like the `document.onscroll` event. Here is my base class:

```
class ThrottledRunner {
    private timerId: number;
    lastTimeRun: number;
    runAtMostEvery = 100;

    // Here is the Method
    runThrottled(action: (e: ThrottledRunner) => void) {
        var now: number = new Date().getTime();

        if (this.timerId == null) {
            if (now - this.lastTimeRun > (3 * this.runAtMostEvery)) {
                action(this);
                this.lastTimeRun = now;
            }
            this.timerId = setTimeout(function (e: ThrottledRunner) {
                e.timerId = null;
                e.lastTimeRun = new Date().getTime();
                action(e);
            }, this.runAtMostEvery);
        }
    }
}
```

My derived class:

```
class MyTest extends ThrottledRunner {

    myProp: string = "works";

    constructor() {
        super();
        window.addEventListener("scroll", () => this.runThrottled(this.onScroll(this)));
        // Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.
        // Could not select overload for 'call' expression.
    }

    onScroll(self: MyTest): void {
        alert(self.myProp);
    }
}
```

Since MyTest derives from ThrottledRunner, `runThrottled()` should accept it as a parmeter but it seems i am wrong. I moved completely to Typescript + vanillajs, so no jQuery answers please.

Comment: `runThrotttled` takes a function/delegate style parameter. You're passing the result of calling `this.OnScroll(this)` to the function though? You may want just `this.OnScroll`?

Comment: @WiredPrairie i have to pass the object to onScroll(), otherwise `this` gets `undefined`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't call `onScroll` the way you are as it's calling it immediately upon executing, when it really needs to wait until your `runThrottled` application is ready. I've changed the `onScroll` method to not need a parameter as the `this` context is set correctly.

If you change your class to:

```
class MyTest extends ThrottledRunner {
    myProp: string = "works";
    constructor() {
        super();
        window.addEventListener("scroll",
             () => this.runThrottled(() => this.onScroll()));
    }

    onScroll(): void {
        console.log(this.myProp);
    }
}
```

The `this` will be correct within the context of the `runThrottled`.

Answer (score 1):

Have you had a look at using underscorejs throttle() function ?

```
_.throttle(function, wait, [options])
```

Creates and returns a new, throttled version of the passed function, that, when invoked repeatedly, will only actually call the original function at most once per every wait milliseconds. Useful for rate-limiting events that occur faster than you can keep up with.

Underscore has a number of extremely useful functions, and has full TypeScript and nuGet support : [underscore.TypeScript.DefinitelyTyped](http://www.nuget.org/packages/underscore.TypeScript.DefinitelyTyped/)

Comment: I knew about Underscore but not about the typed version, thanks! But i'm still wondering how to solve the parameter type issues.